# PHP method get 2 types of objects

Tags: php, methods, arguments

Is it possible to set in method function something like this

```
class myClass{

 public function myMethod($variable stdClass || otherClass){
 }

}
```

I want to do something like, into my `myMethod` can be passed two types of object it is possible in PHP?

Comment: There is no need to describe parameters types in PHP, why do you want to do it ?

Comment: It's my understanding that you don't have to pass an specific type as an argument.

Comment: beacuse i dont want do something like public                      function myMethod($variable){                                                
if($variable instanceof stdClass){}         if($variable instanceof otheClass){}    }
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you'd like to control the input parameter, use an Interface or an abstract class instead:

```
class MyClass {

    public function doSomething(IExpectedObject $input)
    {
        ...
    }

}

interface IExpectedObject{}

class A implements IExpectedObject {}
class B implements IExpectedObject {}
class C {}
```

In this case classes A & B will pass through and C will fail, this can be usefull if your method expect a certain type of objects to process them the same way without caring whether it's an A or B object.

This can also be done with inheritance, depending your needs.

Comment: Is this really a good practice ? Creating an interface only to use it to declare a parameter type seems overkill to me. Especially if there is absolutely no functional link between the two classes. Will you create an interface for each methods of this type you got ?

Comment: Like I said in my answer, using interfaces is a good practice when the method process them without caring for their classes. As he used 'stdClass' in the sample, I presumed the object behind needed a particular processing. IMO I can't see a case where a method should be able to accept and process any object given to it, when you process multiple objects types with same method, isn't it to apply the same operations all of them ? "no functional link between the two classes" so in this case why using same processing method (please excuse my english)

Comment: Yes I agree with you, this kind of problem comes from a conception issue. if the same method is applicable on two classes, these classes should share some methods and attributes by inheritance. But I still think that creating an interface only for this use is overkill. He will end with something like `class MyClass implements InterfaceForMethod1, InterfaceForMethod2, InterfaceForMethod3...` and so loose one of the best sides of OOP : code clarity.

Comment: based on it's sample only it's impossible to say, but I agree with you that interfaces are an overkill if used only to allow methods to accept multiple types, that's not their use. That's more a conception problem.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to precise parameters types in PHP. This is a new feature called [Type Hinting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php) and there is no need to use it.

The only thing you got to do is to handle the fact that your parameter can be an instance of one class or another. You can use [instanceof](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.type.php) to check it :

```
class myClass {
    public function myMethod($param) {
        if($param instanceof MyClass1){
        }
        else if($param instanceof MyClass2){
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: yeap this i know, but i want avoid if $variable instanceof stdClass and if $variable instanceof otheClass than do something. I want check type of object when arguments has passed into method body.

Comment: There is no way to do it for the moment. Even Type Hunting does not allow two methods with the same name, even with different parameters.

Comment: You can always use different design patterns to handle this cases, but this will always be the same thing : switching on the parameters classes. The cleanest way to do it would be to use an interface, to make your two classes implement it, and to use Type Hinting by declaring your parameter is an instance of this interface. But this is the same IMO, and I don't this kind of pattern, where there is no other link between two classes than being taken as parameter by the same method.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set a type, PHP allows you to:

```
class myClass {
    public function myMethod($variable) {

    }
}
```

If it must be one of two types, you can check for it inside of the method, and add a PHPDoc block to tell readers what types `$variable` could be:

```
class myClass {

    /**
     * @param stdClass|myClass $variable
     *
     * @throws InvalidArgumentException in case $variable is not one of the above classes.
     */
    public function myMethod($variable) {
        if (!($variable instanceof stdClass || $variable instanceof myClass)) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('$variable must be either an stdClass or myClass');
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible! You can pass object that implements one [interface](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php) or try to use pattern [factory method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) or simply pass variable

```
 public function myMethod($var) {
    if($var instanceof MyClass) {

    }
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to write the types in the method definition. You can allow any type of parameters to go through in PHP. If you want to check, you can later like this:

```
public function myMethod($var) {
    if(class_name($var) == "MyClass1") { 
        // do something
    } 
    elseif(class_name($var) == "MyClass2") { 
        // do something elese
    } 
    else { 
        // Error
    }
}
```